# Azure DevOps-Add extension that adds custom tab to Pipeline / Release Definition page (not the summary page)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I want to add a custom tab to the Pipeline or Release definition page as shown in the screenshot, where all the runs are shown (not to be confused with the Build summary page, which is for each individual Pipeline run)

I couldn't find a sample, is it possible?
[image: ss]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such contribution target to add a tab to the Pipeline or Release definition page. You may submit a suggestion at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21